# How to pass a property as argument to function in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I got a movieclip named `mcButton` with a property of `scaleX`, i got to pass it to a function that manipulates mcButton.scaleX.

```
manipulateValue(mcButton.scaleX);

function manipulateValue(mcProperty:?)
{
   mcProperty += 2;

   ..execute other things here...
}
```

The function executes the same code for several property and several movieclip so I got to make it generic. Any help on how I could do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to manipulate several properties.. How about pass the mcButton object?

```
manipulateValue(mcButton);

function manipulateValue(obj:MovieClip)
{
    obj.scaleX += 2;

    // manipulate other properties
    obj.scaleY += 2;
    obj.width = ....;
    obj.height = ....;

    ..execute other things here...
}
```

**Updated : Aug 19 13:55(JST)**

OK. If you want to pass one property at once, how about this?

```
manipulateValue(mcButton, "scaleX");
manipulateValue(mcButton, "scaleY");

function manipulateValue(obj:MovieClip, prop: String)
{
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
        obj[prop] += 2;
    }

    ..execute other things here...
}
```

Comment: the problem is, for a particular property like scaleX, it will be used for several cases of "if.." "else if" and so on. So if we got to manipulate M number properties, you got to handle NxM times line of codes while in fact we could only do that using N line of codes.

Comment: So what is wrong with this solution?  As long as all your objects are MovieClips this seems ideal.

Comment: yhea, but the `objects` are `properties` of `MovieClips`. I am looking for a way to run it this way: `manipulateValue(mc.stageX)`, `manipulateValue(mc.scaleY)`, `manipulate(mc.alpha)`, or so on, it depends on what property we want to manipulate.

A solution to my query can make the `function` flexible at runtime.